# ESP8266 CCLOCK Odd behavior

Tags: esp8266, timing, assembly

I'm trying to write some extremely fast code for the ESP8266, so I'm trying to figure out how to time things.  I've discovered `CCLOCK`, a register that reflects the number of clock cycles since startup. (https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/4632#issuecomment-380632906, and other references.) In testing it out, though, I've encountered some weird behavior.  Consider the following code:

```
static inline volatile uint32_t asm_ccount(void) {
    uint32_t r;
    asm volatile ("rsr %0, ccount" : "=r"(r));
    return r;
}

char outgoingPacket[4];

...

void loop() {

  // ... some stuff ...

  uint32_t startTime = asm_ccount();
  uint32_t stopTime = asm_ccount();
  uint32_t elapsed = stopTime-startTime;
  
  outgoingPacket[0] = (elapsed >> 24) & 0xff;
  outgoingPacket[1] = (elapsed >> 16) & 0xff;
  outgoingPacket[2] = (elapsed >> 8) & 0xff;
  outgoingPacket[3] = elapsed & 0xff;
  Udp.beginPacket(targetUdpIp, targetUdpPort);
  Udp.write(outgoingPacket, 4);
  Udp.endPacket();
}
```

(On my computer, I have basically the following Java code running to receive these messages:)

```
    while (true) {
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
      socket.receive(packet);

      byte[] data = packet.getData();
      StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
      StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < packet.getLength(); i++) {
        sb1.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toString(((int) data[i]) & 0xFF, 2)).replace(' ', '0'));
        sb2.append(String.format("%2s", Integer.toString(((int) data[i]) & 0xFF, 16)).replace(' ', '0'));
      }
      System.out.println(sb1 + " " + Integer.parseInt(sb2.toString(), 16));
    }
```

(Yes, it's a little hacky, I know, but the results have seemed correct.)

Now, most of the time, the output looks like

```
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
```

But about 5 times in 77000, I'll get lines like

```
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000110101000 424
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
...
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000010010100001 1185
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
...
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000010001001100 1100
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 1
```

I ran the code for 1 minute 4 seconds, and got 3 counts of 424, 1 of 1100, and 1 of 1185.  It seems particularly odd that 424 would show up three times.

Given that, as far as I understand, the relevant lines of code (the two calls to `asm_ccount`) would have been compiled to a given set of instructions, I'd have expected it to take exactly the same number of cycles every time.

Why is this not happening?

Is it interrupts?  Something something caching?  Does that register not actually work as claimed or as I understand?  Have I done something dumb in the transmission or logging code?  Something else?

Comment: You've got interrupts running and interrupting your code.  Those take some cycles to run.

Comment: aHAH!  I think you're right.  When I disable interrupts around the critical code, its timing becomes almost perfectly stable.  ...But then it stops working after a few dozen loops, so I guess I can't do that, haha.  If you want to make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got interrupts running and interrupting your code. Those take some cycles to run.